# Make branch point to the tip of the branch that originated it

Tags: git, branch, branching-and-merging

I performed QA of a feature in the system doing the following:

- Created a `staging` branch from `master`.
- Merged the feature branch `task-123` into `staging`.
- Deployed `staging` to the test server.
- QA'd the functionality.

The QA failed, and now I want to make `staging` point back to the latest commit of `master`, so it will be ready for QA of other feature branches.

How can I do it using relative branching reference (no hashes)?

Comment: Wouldn't resetting staging to master work?

Comment: Did you ever find the results you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want, but this is such basic "git 101" that I can't help feeling that I'm missing something and you want something more compilcated.

If you want to reset `staging` back to where you started

```
<in the staging branch>
git reset --hard $(git merge-base HEAD origin/master) 
git push --force
```

If you want to reset `staging` to the current state of master

```
<in the staging branch>
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
git push --force
```